# Update CDATA section using XmlUpdate MSBuild task?

Tags: xml, msbuild

Anybody know how to set the value of an XmlUpdate MSBuild task so that the output is wrapped in a CDATA section?

I've tried:

```
Value="&#60;![CDATA[@(Readme)]]&#62;"
```

and

```
Value="&lt;![CDATA[@(Readme)]]&gt;"
```

But both output HTML encoded **<** and **>** tags.

Many thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDATA is just a convenience for outputting text without having to escape special characters such as `<>&"'`. Since `XmlUpdate` does properly escape the text it should not be necessary to require a CDATA section; the XML will be equivalent.

Comment: If the application which uses the updated XML file expects it as CDATA, would there be any conflict? (ie, double escaping)

Comment: I doubt that the application *expects* it as CDATA, since from an XML perspective this is just a text node. Compliant XML parsers should threat them as equivalent, and the application in fact shouldn't notice a difference in the common case.